# Set cin.fail() manually

Tags: c++, cin

I want to raise cin.fail() error if inputted integer greater then fixed number? How can I do that?

```
int a;
cin >> a;
if (a > 10)
   //raise cin.fail()
```

Comment: [std::basic_ios::setstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `failbit` using [`setstate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate):

[Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SDzWJKA9AFjrxIQm)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int a;

    std::cin >> a;

    if(a > 10)   
        std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "fails\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I also learned that this can be implemented with cin.clear() method

Comment: @YaroslavHladkyi, glad I could help, yes, `cin.clear()` has the same effect, the only advantage of this method is that it's more explicit and, therefore, easier to understand for an observer.